# how to copy and paste code, in color, keeping line numbers, using netbeans 7.2.1

Tags: netbeans, copy, paste

I need to print out code for school. and i would like to keep the line numbers from netbeans and the auto coloring that it does. is there a plug in i could use?

Answer (score 5):

If you can use html you can do this:

open the file you need -> **`file`** -> **`Print to HTML ...`** -> Select **`print to file`** or **`print to clipboard`** -> check **`show linenumbers`**

For printing via printer: **`file`** -> **`print ->`** customize at **`print options`**